# Extract images from PDF file using PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, web, ocr, resume

I want to get the picture in the resume PDF or make a copy of it. I already tried some code from the internet but it is not working or the image must have effect like shadow or glow to work, I need a PHP code that can get image/Picture. For example, when i upload resume PDF, I want to get the 2x2 picture from it or make a copy of it.

These is the code that I already tried but it only works when the images have effects.

```
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');
class extractImagesFromPdf {
    public function toByteArray($file01)
    {
        if (!($fp = fopen($file01, "r")))
            die ("can not open file: " . $file01) ;

        $file = file_get_contents($file01);
        $byteArr = str_split($file);

        $length = sizeof($byteArr) ;
        $data = "" ;
        for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $data .= base64_encode($byteArr[$i]);
        }
        return $data ;
    }

    function main ($subSerial, $fileContent)
    {
        $client = new nusoap_client("http://www.biclim.com/WS/BCService?wsdl", true);

        $params[] = array('subSerial' => $subSerial,
            'fileContent' => $fileContent
            );

        $result = $client->call("extractImagesFromPdf", $params);
        $images = $result["extractImagesFromPdfResponse"];
        print_r($images);
        $i = 0;
        $theDate = date("dmY_His") ;
        foreach($images AS $image) {
            $fp = fopen('d:/fileImages_Page' . $image['pageNumber'] . "_image" . $i . "_" . $theDate . "." . $image['imageType'], 'w');
            print "\nExtracting Image " . $i . " in Page :" . $image['pageNumber'] ;
            fwrite($fp, base64_decode($image['content']));
            fclose ($fp);
            $i = $i + 1;
        }
    }
}
$subSerial = "DEMO";
$extractImagesFromPdf = new extractImagesFromPdf() ;
$fileContent = $extractImagesFromPdf->toByteArray("D:/2.pdf") ;
$extractImagesFromPdf->main($subSerial, $fileContent);
```

Comment: Share the code which you have tried

Comment: I already updated it.